# transformPoint using tf::Transform?

Tags: ros, stampedtransform, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I need to save a transform (world->Kinect frame) at a specific time, and use this transform to convert a point in world coordinate frame to a point in that old Kinect frame after several seconds.

To do this, I first tried using tf::Listener::transformPoint. However, to my knowledge the only way to save a transform at a specific time is by using tf::lookupTransform, which can save the transform at specific time in tf::Transform type. My problem is that in this tf::Transform type, there is no function such as transformPoint.

Am I left to implement such function myself, or is there a one that is named differently?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42266/transformpoint-using-tf::transform?/) by [bkim](https://answers.ros.org/users/3018/bkim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2012-08-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bkim](https://answers.ros.org/users/3018/bkim/) on 2012-08-24**:
I took a look at time travel tutorial in tf wiki: http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Time%20travel%20with%20tf%20%28C%2B%2B%29, but it does not explain about transforming a point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tf::Transform class overloads the `*` operator. One version takes a tf::Vector3 which is how a point is represented and returns the transformed point.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4